# Sorting Aggregated DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe and I aggredated it as below. I want to sort (descending) it according to 'mean'. I m using below code but it gives an error.

[image]

```
df_agg = df.groupby('Subject Field').agg({'seniority_level':['min','mean','median','max']})

df_agg.sort_values(by='mean',ascending=False).head(10)
```

Error

[image]

Comment: what's the error? please provide a [mcve] to reproduce your dataset. p.s you're probably looking for `sort_index` not `values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your aggregated dataframe has a multi level column index. So you need to address this by specifying both `senority_level` and `mean`.

```
df_agg.sort_values(('seniority_level', 'mean'), ascending=False)
```

Quick check to demonstrate:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Accounting': [1, 2, 3],
    'Acoustics': [4, 5, 6],
}).melt(var_name='Subject Field', value_name='seniority_level')
df_agg = df.groupby('Subject Field').agg(
    {'seniority_level':['min', 'mean', 'median']}
)
```

```py
df_agg.sort_values(('seniority_level','mean'), ascending=True)
```

```
              seniority_level            
                          min mean median
Subject Field                            
Accounting                  1    2      2
Acoustics                   4    5      5
```

```py
df_agg.sort_values(('seniority_level','mean'), ascending=False)
```

```
              seniority_level            
                          min mean median
Subject Field                            
Acoustics                   4    5      5
Accounting                  1    2      2
```